How to format on save in neovim
This is the autocmd to format on save for python files, but I am not able to get it working for .js, .ts, .jsx, .tsx:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "BufWritePost",
    {pattern = "*.py", group = "AutoFormat", callback = function()
            vim.cmd("silent !black --quiet %")
            vim.cmd("edit")
        end}
)

I have tried this and I don't know how to add prettier so I have just used the vim autocmd:
vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd(
    "BufWritePost",
    {pattern = "*.js", group = "AutoFormat", callback = function()
            vim.lsp.buf.format({async = false})
        end}
)


To format your Javascript code with prettier:

install manually prettier (depends on your OS / distribution)
install vim-prettier plugin (https://github.com/prettier/vim-prettier) and configure it to format your Javascript code on save.

You could also install and use formatter.nvim Neovim plugin (https://github.com/mhartington/formatter.nvim) and configure it to use Prettier to format your code.
